# Reading Timestamp column from Oracle using Java.. rs.getString(index)

Tags: oracle, jdbc, timestamp

While reading a Timestamp column data from Oracle 10g using Java 6, I read it as follows:

```
String str = rs.getString(index);
```

I don't want to use `rs.getTimestamp()`. Now, when I do the same with a Date column, I get an appropriate String representation of Date. But with Timestamp I get a String as follows:

```
2009-5-3 12:36:57. 618000000
```

I don't understand why a space is introduced just before the milliseconds. This makes the timestamp I read unparseable by pre-defined timestamp formats. Any idea as to why am I getting a space before milliseconds?

Comment: You're right, the JDBC standard for timestamps doesn't include the space. But why wouldn't you read the timestamp using `rs.getTimestamp()`?

Comment: Legacy codes are best not questioned  :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is what I am going to to and does seem like a feasible solution to me.

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("..");
ResultSetMetaData rsmt = rs.getMetaData();
int columnIndex = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
if (rsmt.getColumnType(columnIndex) == 93) { // ts field - ref. -> http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/jdbc/recipes/ResultSet-ColumnType.shtml
    Timestamp tsTemp = this.getTimestamp(columnIndex);
    return tsTemp.toString(); // this does give the timestamp in correct format
}
columnIndex ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing an implicit conversion to a string, so the formatting is determined by your database session's `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` setting, which is derived from your Java Locale. That is a weird format though, so perhaps it's somehow being overridden.

As you often don't have control over such things, and you might get an unexpected change in an environment that breaks your code, it's generally safer to specify the format in your query. If you really need to retrieve it with `getString()`, rather than

```
select timestamp_field from ...
```

do something like

```
select to_char(timestamp_field, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') from ...
```

Alternatively you could change your Locale; or set the format in the session by executing an `alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'` before your query, but you'd have to do it in every session (or use a logon trigger) and it could potentially have unexpected impacts elsewhere, particularly if using connection pooling. Explicitly getting the data out of the database in the format you want is more obvious, and won't break if someone else changes something later.

Comment: Thanks for the NLS format information. Including a format within the query itself was a good option if I knew which column will be of Timestamp data type. But, in this case, the tables are generated on the fly and the column data types can vary. So, can't use the formats within the queries.

Comment: @akkyy Just out of interest, what is your current Locale; and are you able to see what your session has in the `nls_session_parameters` view? It might be useful to know how it's getting that value as there may already be something setting the format, either within your code or in a logon trigger in the database.

Comment: Calling `alter session` might be safest for you if you really can't determine the column types (I guess building the query dynamically from column types in all_tab_columns is out of the question?). But I'd be concerned about the possibility that someone else is already setting it and you might clash, causing problems elsewhere.

Comment: NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM

Comment: @akkyy - is that as seen from your application, or from another client (e.g. SQL*Plus)? I'd assume the latter. So either your Locale is setting a strange value - which appears to be `FMYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSX FF9` from your example - or something in your code is setting it for the session.

Comment: Since you mentioned you don't know which columns are timestamps in advance, have you checked that the value is actually coming from a timestamp column, and isn't a pre-formatted string in a varchar?

Comment: The value is coming from Timestamp column for sure.

Comment: Is there any way of checking the Locale and the values it sets for various formats?